# image fails to appear in .Rpres

Tags: r, image, r-markdown

In exploring Rstudio presentations, I ran into a presumably simple, but vexing, problem that my searches have not solved.  In short, an image imported into my presentation does not appear; only the box with alt text does.  With the same import in an Rmarkdown file, the image appears.  I am running OSX 10.9.5 and RStudio 0.98.1091.  Code examples below:

This .Rmd shows my image:

```
---
title: "Another Try"
author: "Me"
date: "today"
output: html_document
---
This is my image.

![my image](/path/to/my/file/myimage.png)
```

This .Rpres does not show my image:

```
anotherTry
========================================================
author: Me
date: Today

My Image
========================================================

![my image](/path/to/my/file/myimage.png)
```

Answer (score 2):

The following (in file `file.Rpres`) works for me, with rstudio.

```
Title slide
===========
author: me
date: now

Test slide
==========

Below is a test image

![my image](testimage.png)
```

[image: screen snapshot]

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be that the image need to be in the source folder of the presentation

`![my image](/path/to/my/file/myimage.png)` doesn't work but

`![my image](myimage.png)`  works, if the file is in the same directory